# How to make Button with Image and textview in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button

[Button with image and Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cDsV.png) 
if it is not possible with button than please recommend the other way.

Comment: try `TextView` with `drawableTop` or create a compound view

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a button, use any layout eg. Linear Layout and place the image and text on it and add a click listener to the layout. It'll work the same way, plus more customization.